# Optimize the next permutations in n queens puzzle

Tags: algorithm, rust

I am solving the n queens problem.

I use an array of `1..=n` to represent the position of the queen, and then keep finding the next permutation until I judge that this permutation is a solution.

```rust
/// Returns a bool value indicating whether the next permutation exists
pub fn next_permutation(arrange: &mut [usize]) -> bool {
    let last_ascending = match arrange.windows(2).rposition(|w| w[0] < w[1]) {
        Some(i) => i,
        None => {
            arrange.reverse();
            return false;
        }
    };

    let swap_with = arrange[last_ascending + 1..]
        .binary_search_by(|n| usize::cmp(&arrange[last_ascending], n).then(Ordering::Less))
        .unwrap_err();
    arrange.swap(last_ascending, last_ascending + swap_with);
    arrange[last_ascending + 1..].reverse();
    true
}

pub fn is_solution(arrange: &[usize]) -> bool {
    let iter = arrange.iter().enumerate();
    iter.clone().all(|(i, &j)| {
        iter.clone()
            .filter(|&(c, _)| c != i)
            .all(|(p, &q)| i as isize - j as isize != p as isize - q as isize && i as usize + j != p as usize + q)
    })
}
```

Now my problem is that the `next_permutation` function does not quite meet my needs.

For example `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, the next permutation is `[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]`, this results in a lot of wasted judgment.

It can be found that `[1, 2, _, _, _]` does not meet the requirements , the next permutation to check should be say `[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]`.

How do I optimize the `next_permutation` function to implement this process?

Comment: implement what ? reread your own question

Comment: @Stargateur implement  `next_permutation_to_check`

Comment: Don't think "permutation", instead think "what position can the queen take in the current column given the positions of the queens in the previous columns?" and choose the columns one after the other. So: column 1, the queen may go anywhere, say I put it as "1". Now column 2, the queen may not go in 1 or 2 because of the first one, say I put it as "3". And so on until you either fill all the columns or find a column that can't be filled and need to backtrack.